# Synonym for 'every x minutes'?

Tags: word-request

Is there a synonym for the 'every x minutes' construct?
The phrase I want to rephrase is 'the system generates a command every x minutes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word *intervals*:

> The system generates a command at five-minute intervals.

Wordnik shows one definition of *interval* is:

> **[interval](https://www.wordnik.com/words/interval)** (*n.*) The amount of time between two specified instants, events, or states.

Answer (score 1):

Words like *hourly*, *daily*, *weekly* could serve as one-word synonyms for that construction in some cases, but they're much more specific units than you seem to be looking for.